# Polymorphic functions over chains of nested tuples

Tags: haskell, fold, type-level-computation

Suppose I have a list of types, of kind `[*]`:

```
let Ts = '[Int, Bool, Char]
```

I want to convert this to a chain of tuples:

```
type family Tupled (ts :: [*]) z :: *
type instance Tupled (t ': ts) z = (t, Tupled ts z)
type instance Tupled '[] z = z
```

So far so good:

```
> :kind! Tupled Ts ()
Tupled Ts () :: *
= (Int, (Bool, (Char, ())))
```

Now I’d like to be able to write a type `Fun` to represent functions that are polymorphic in the “bottom” of this chain. For example, `Fun Ts Ts` should work on either of these types:

```
(Int, (Bool, (Char, (String, ()))))
(Int, (Bool, (Char, (Word, (ByteString, ())))))
```

I tried this:

```
newtype Fun as bs = Fun
  { unfun :: forall z. Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z }
```

But it fails to typecheck:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Tupled bs z’ with ‘Tupled bs z0’
NB: ‘Tupled’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘z0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z
  Actual type: Tupled as z0 -> Tupled bs z0
In the ambiguity check for the type of the constructor ‘Fun’:
  Fun :: forall z. Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the definition of data constructor ‘Fun’
In the newtype declaration for ‘Fun’
```

I’ve seen recommendations to use a data family to avoid problems with injectivity:

```
data family Tupled (ts :: [*]) z :: *
data instance Tupled (t ': ts) z = Cons t (Tupled ts z)
data instance Tupled '[] z = Nil
```

And indeed that makes `Fun` compile, but it looks like that gets me “stuck” in the land of `Cons` and `Nil` when I’m looking to work with tuples, like this:

```
Fun $ \ (i, (b, (c, z))) -> (succ i, (not b, (pred c, z)))
```

Can I work around this somehow?

Comment: Why not `type Fun as bs = forall z. Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia: I want to be able to pass a `Fun` as an argument to a `Fun`, so I need the `newtype` to hide the impredicativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `AllowAmbiguousTypes`. From GHC 8, the ambiguity check is completely superfluous, because any (fundamentally resolvable) ambiguity can be resolved with type applications. Also, your case seems to be just a false positive for ambiguity check, since we can clearly use `Fun` even without type applications.

Comment: I should have noted this in the question, but enabling this seems to make no difference—I get the same error message. I’m using GHC 8.0.2 from the `lts-8.9` Stack resolver.

Comment: This [file](http://lpaste.net/354579) is accepted by both GHC 8.0.1 and 8.0.2. I'm not sure what's wrong on your side (also, I used closed type familiy there but open works just as well).

Comment: Aha, `newtype Fun as bs = Fun (forall z. …)` typechecks, but `… = Fun { unfun :: forall z. … }` does not. I was confused because the *definition* of `unfun` is considered an ambiguous *use site*. Making it a separate function and using a type application `unfun :: forall as bs z. Fun as bs -> Tupled as z -> Tupled bs z; unfun (Fun f) as = f @z as` solves the problem. Thanks for helping me figure this out. :)